# Perplexing definition of Laplace transform given by Google

Tags: definition, laplace-transform

If you google [laplace transform formula](https://www.google.com/search?q=laplace%20transform%20formula) today, most likely you'll see a Google knowledge panel with a definition like this:

[image]

This $t'$ at differential's place and then the description of it as "first derivative of the function f(t)" doesn't make much sense to me. Apparently, knowledge panels take information from Google's Knowledge Graph ([according to Google](https://support.google.com/knowledgepanel/answer/9163198)) and I don't think there is a way to find the source of this formula.

So is Google wrong? Or am I missing something?

Comment: It should be $\text{dt}$ not $t'$.

Comment: Looks pretty wrong to me too!